# Stop on Input on Script

Tags: python

I get the following error in my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\scanner\test.py", line 42, in <module>
    cont = input("new start y/n: ")
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

But this error only occurs if I use "result_QR = QR()" and as soon as I switch off the section (#result_QR = QR()) everything works

Strangely enough, it only comes when I run QR(). As soon as you turn it off it works perfectly. I've tried so many things but haven't found a solution

Can someone check this and help me find the error.

my code:

```
import colorama

colorama.init()


    def code_138():
    code_input = input("Scan Code 123: ")
    code = '990012341234567890'
    result = code_input == code
    if result == 'OK': print('CODE 138: ' + colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'TRUE' + colorama.Fore.RESET)
    print(
        'CODE 138:                  ' + colorama.Fore.RED + 'FALSE' + colorama.Fore.RESET)


def QR():
    print("Scan Code QR. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z to next")
    code_input = []
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        code_input.append(line)

    code = ['SPC', '0200', '1', 'CH9300762011123456789', 'S', 'Test AG', 'Test X-Y-Z', '1', '8888',
            'xxxxx', 'CH', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '999.00', 'EUR', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'NON', '',
            'Test', 'EPD']
    result = code_input == code
    if result == 'OK': print('QR-Code: ' + colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'TRUE' + colorama.Fore.RESET)
    print(
        'QR-Code:                   ' + colorama.Fore.RED + 'FALSE' + colorama.Fore.RESET)


def main():
    result_138 = code_138()
    result_QR = QR()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    while True:
        cont = input("new start y/n: ")
        cont = cont.lower()

        while cont.lower() not in ("y", "n"):
            cont = input("new start y/n ")

        if cont == "n":
            print("Send")
            break

        if cont == "y":
            print('')
            print('')
            main()
```

full error:

```
C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\scanner\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\vonaht\PycharmProjects\handscanner\test.py 
Scan Code 123: 123
CODE 138:                  FALSE
Scan Code QR. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z to next
asdf
asdf^D
QR-Code:                   FALSE
new start y/n: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\scanner\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    cont = input("new start y/n: ")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How are you running this? Is it in a shell where STDIN is left open for input?

Comment: I run it in Pycharm, the EOF error occurs after the process exits with exit code 1. I added the error above

Comment: Afaik, the problem is that Ctrl-D closes stdin. You'd better use another way to signal the end of the QR input. And btw, `if result == 'OK':` is wrong, since result is a boolean.